# Uploading a data file to my Google app engine app

Tags: google-app-engine

How may I upload a data file to my Google app engine folder using any standard file transfer protocol e.g. SFTP, WebDav etc.?

This is so I can use a regular desktop file transfer client

So far the only ways I've found are Google proprietary, and web form upload.

Comment: You can't really use anything other than the `gcloud` tool. The file system on GAE is read-only so once you deploy a version of your app - it stays like that until a new version replaces it.What web form upload are you referring to?

Comment: To this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload , though the read-only you meniton would make it ineffective for the stated requirement.

Comment: Uploading to Google App Engine (your original question) and uploading to Google Cloud Storage (the link you are pointing) are two different things. Yes, you should be able to mount a Google Cloud Storage bucket as a local directory and easily transfer any files to & from (see more here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse ).

Comment: Indeed. As I said "ineffective for the stated requirement". Thanks for the mount option -- sadly not available on Windows I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE's filesystem is readonly, i.e. you can't really make changes to any of the files once the app is deployed.

You can upload your files to GCS by [mounting a bucket as a local directory](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) but as you noted that option doesn't seem to be available on Windows.

You could also use `gsutil` to transfer files to/from the bucket, like that: `gsutil cp *.txt gs://my-bucket`, even on Windows ([see more details here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)) but if you want a GUI client - just google for gui clients for gcs, many storage browsers i.e. more or less advanced ftp clients seem to support it (see for example Cyberduck, CrossFTP, etc).

Comment: I'm guessing this answer would be true with 'really' removed :) I.e. "You can't." Thanks.